# Javascript Array.prototype.sort() unintentionally mutating array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of integers so as to put them in the order that will form the greatest integer.  For example, [99, 901] should be sorted as [99, 901] because 99,901 > 90,199.  And [91, 991] should be sorted as [991, 91] because 99,191 > 91,991.

To do this I am using Array.prototype.sort(), passing in the compare function in the code block below as the argument.  The argument to this compare function is an array of arrays (each integer is first split into an array of single-digit integers): [[9,1],[9,9,1]].

My problem is that while this compare function works, it returns an array which has some elements truncated.  Apparently this is due to the fact that I'm calling Array.prototype.shift() when it's necessary to compare the second (or third, fourth, etc.) elements of two integers.  I didn't expect this but can't find a work-around.

For example, the code below outputs

```
[[9],[1,9]]
```

whereas what I need is

```
[[9,9],[9,1,9]]
```

Can you tell me how I can revise my compare function to get the output I am looking for?

Thanks!

```
var compare = function(a, b){

    if(a.length === 1 || b.length === 1){
        return (b[0] - a[0]);
    }

    else if(a[0] !== b[0]){
        return compare(a[0], b[0]);
    }

    else if(a[0] === b[0]){
        if(a.length !== 1){
            a.shift();
        }
        if(b.length !== 1){
            b.shift();
        }
        return compare(a, b);
    }
};

var example = function(){

    var digits = [[9,9],[9,1,9]];
    digits.sort(compare);
    console.log(digits);
};

example();
```

Comment: `shift()` mutates the array.  Don't do that.

Comment: Tip: Just convert those arrays to string and compare those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest (yet inefficient) way to do this is to copy your arrays:

```
var compare = function(a, b){
a = a.slice();
b = b.slice();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I thought I'd tried something along those lines and it wasn't working.  But this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Although you already accepted an answer, I would still like to answer to your question... *"how I can revise my compare function?"*, because you really need to: it currently gives wrong results for some inputs, like here:

```js
var compare = function(a, b){

    if(a.length === 1 || b.length === 1){
        return (b[0] - a[0]);
    }

    else if(a[0] !== b[0]){
        return compare(a[0], b[0]);
    }

    else if(a[0] === b[0]){
        if(a.length !== 1){
            a.shift();
        }
        if(b.length !== 1){
            b.shift();
        }
        return compare(a, b);
    }
};

console.log('this should return a number greater than 0:');
console.log(compare([8,1],[8,1,9,2]));
```

Here is how to correct it, and do it without mutation also:

```js
var compare = function(a, b){
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length || i < b.length; i++) {
        var diff = b[i % b.length] - a[i % a.length];
        if (diff) return diff;
    }
    return 0;
};

console.log('this should return a number greater than 0:');
console.log(compare([8,1],[8,1,9,2]));
var digits = [[8,1],[8,1,9,2]];
digits.sort(compare);
console.log('sorted:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(digits));
```